# How do I append keystrokes to a keydown EventListener?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, addeventlistener

I have a preexisting list of keystrokes listened for via `keydown` and am trying to append to it without overriding it.

```
 document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
if(hotkeyBool == 1) {
    if([16, 33, 34, 37, 38, 39, 40, 49, 50, 65, 66, 72, 76, 90, 219, 221].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {
        if(top.ActionDelay < 50) {
            switch (e.keyCode) {
                case 33: // PAGE UP
                    Move(4);
                    break;
                case 34: // PAGE DOWN
                    Move(5);
                    break;
                case 37: // ►
                    Move(3);
                    break;
                case 38: // ▲
                    Move(0);
                    break;
                case 39: // ◄
                    Move(2);
                    break;
                case 40: // ▼
                    Move(1);
                    break;
                ...
```

I would like to append another keydown `'z'` for running another function `ashIt()` without affecting this existing list, using vanilla JavaScript. Whenever I use the following code, whether I attach it to the whole DOM or only a part of it, the above gets overridden and non-functional:

```
 document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
   if (hotkeyBool) {
     if ([90].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {
       if (top.ActionDelay < 50) {
         ashIt();
         e.preventDefault();
       }
     }
   }
 }, false);
```

Is what I'm attempting to do possible? If so, is it possible without rewriting the whole thing in some library? I don't have direct access to the preexisting list, else I would just append it there.

Comment: If you use `addEventListener()` to attach two different listener functions to the same element for the same event then normally both functions will be called in the order they are bound, unless the first listener calls [`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation) (which yours doesn't). Given your two listeners are doing things in response to different keys there shouldn't be a problem unless the `hotkeyBool` variable is being reset by code not shown or something like that? Can you provide a demo?

Comment: I think your `ashit()` function returns  (joke)

Comment: `ashIt()` Thanks for not being helpful...

Comment: Impossible to guess with that is provided. It should work, too many unknowns to guess why it does not.